# Flipping a boolean value

Tags: c#, boolean, bit-manipulation

I have a small C# problem that I'm sure must be easy to solve, but I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong.

I have a debug mode in my game which is turned on when a boolean value **debugMode** is set to true. The variable is held within a **gameInfo** object, referenced in my **GameInfo** class. I want to make it so that I can toggle debug mode on and off by pressing the "I" key on the keyboard. Here's what I tried:

```
if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.I))
      GameInfo.gameInfo.debugMode = !GameInfo.gameInfo.debugMode;
```

The problem is that nothing happens when I press "I". If I do the following I am able to turn debug mode *off* so I know the idea works:

```
if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.I))
          GameInfo.gameInfo.debugMode = false;
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I can of course solve it by using a couple of if statements to turn a true to a false and vice versa, but that it long-winded compared with the simple statement above.

Thanks a lot for any help you can offer :)

Comment: Which architecture have you use?

Comment: I'm sorry but I've no idea what you mean! I'm fairly inexperienced with programming.

Comment: It's unusual if the second sample you tried works, could you try something like `GameInfo.gameInfo.debugMode = GameInfo.gameInfo.debugMode ? false : true;`?

Comment: How often are you calling this code? Think about what happens if you call it twice while the user is still pressing the key. (For example, if the key is down for 100ms and you call the code once every ~50ms)

Comment: Use the debugger and look why you don't enter the `if`

Comment: This statement is correct so it's something else which make it fails. By any chance is this statement included in a method which is called upon an event ? Sometimes input events are triggered twice for multiple reasons. Also is there any other part of your code which could act on debugMode value ?

Comment: I've just given that a go @KeyurPATEL but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @AndyLatham So its definitely what the others suggest, you may be calling it multiple times. Could you show the code of that function? Whether it is a OnKeyDown or how you are calling it would help us help you.

Comment: Indeed, it seems plausible to me that the problem is that the toggle is happening multiple times. Try adding a Debug.Trace to your program that writes out to the debugger output every time the value is toggled, and see if it is being toggled more often than you'd like.

Comment: If Keyur version doesn't work, I'm virtually sure your toggle is triggered twice in a row. Figure out why.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I did think about that, but surely the debug mode should flip on or off some of the time?

Comment: @Kinxil This is the only time the debugMode variable is ever altered in the game.

Comment: @AndyLatham Then you're doing this operation at least twice. As I mentionned, it might be event double call. However, I also thought about something else : If you're checking your key value down on a Framerate (since you're obviously doing a game) time basis (let's say, every frame of your game), then your key press will mostly be longer than the time between two frames. In that case, you need a filter. The proper way : create a flag, set it on I pressed down, doesn't check for I pressed down until it have been released (unset flag on I released).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does require you to have another flag, but it will prevent the Key event from being handled multiple times at once.

```
bool keyPressRegistered = false;

...

if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.I) && !keyPressRegistered)
{
    keyPressRegistered = true;
    GameInfo.gameInfo.debugMode = !GameInfo.gameInfo.debugMode;
}

...

keyPressRegistered = !(keyPressRegistered && keyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.I));
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! This has solved my problem, although I had to change the last line to an if condition to make it work: if (keyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.I)) {keyPressRegistered = false;}